# Why can I get the correct result when I use the function writes to a local variable in Compose ？

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The Code A is based the [article](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#any-order).

*I was told that if the function writes to a local variable, this code will not be thread-safe or correct, and I will get the wrong result.*

1: I test it with the Code A, but I always get the correct result, why?

2: Is the Code B correct?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun ListWithBug(myList: List<String>) {
    var items = 0

    Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween) {
        Column {
            for (item in myList) {
                Text("Item: $item")
                items++ // Avoid! Side-effect of the column recomposing.
            }
        }
        Text("Count: $items")
    }
}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApp {
                ListWithBug(mutableListOf("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","k","j"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Code B**

```
@Composable
fun ListWithBug(myList: List<String>) {
    var items by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween) {
        Column {
            for (item in myList) {
                Text("Item: $item")
                items++ // Avoid! Side-effect of the column recomposing.
            }
        }
        Text("Count: $items")
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add [kotlin] (or other used language) tag to your posts so your code will be highlighted and easier to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work as expected under practical scenarios. It might be working for you because you are testing it in isolation. Whenever a Composable recomposes, it will re-initialise all the variables that are declared in it. Hence, if something s=triggers a recomposition of the Composable, it will re-initialise the `items` var to 0. I said it would not work in practical application because over that place, there's a pool of composables the user is interacting with. A press of a button could cause multiple recompositions so it is not at all safe to maintain this state in the local composable.

The second approach MIGHT be fine, but is not at all recommended since it can cause state inconsistency among other composables, because ideally, you should store all of your UI state in a `viewmodel`. It acts as a single source of truth and all the composables can read the state from a single place that way.

You can learn about state hoisting in order to use viewmodels consistently with Compose. Just check out [this codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state).

Maybe specifically [this](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state#8) page, but surely give a go to the codelab on the whole.